# embed html from another file into a markdown document

Tags: html, markdown

If I have an html file somewhere in the same folder as a markdown document, is there any way to embed the entire file inside a markdown document, so that the html will be rendered correctly (not just the code displayed)?

Comment: I don't think that in markdown there are facilities for snippets though there might be some extension that can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown doesn't support includes out-of-the-box. You need to use one of the existing flavors or static site generators that support markdown or/and HTML inclusions. For example, [DocFX](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/spec/docfx_flavored_markdown.html#file-inclusion)

Answer (score 1):

You can't include other Markdown files in Readme (Readme is usually Markdown file). You can use the "Quote" (See example below)

> This is Quote

```
> This is Quote
```

You can see my [Markdown guide here](https://github.com/igorkowalczyk/only-md)

Comment: Thank you Majonez.exe. I wish I could split bounties and give you 25 point and @Anton Zolotukhin 25 points. However, it was not possible so, I upvoted your answer and marked as correct. As Anton Zolotukhin was the first answer, I followed Stackoverflow rules. Cheers

Comment: Thank you, but I don't interesed in the points, I help because I can. Points are just a bonus :)